# Fetching words from Firestore does not update LazyColumn Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, compose-recomposition

```
@Composable
fun getData() {
        var wordData = arrayListOf<Word>()
        db.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                wordData.add(document.toObject(Word::class.java))
            }
        }
        LazyColumn {
            items(wordData) {  word ->
                WordCard(word = word)
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to use Lazy Column to show all of my words data, these are my WordCard codes.

```
@Composable
fun WordCard(word: Word) {
    Text(text = word.word, color = Color.Black, modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Gray).padding(12.dp))
}
```

Comment: Besides z.y's answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-49ee736dc07d), this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) and this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is a `firebase` issue, but I notice this.

```
var wordData = arrayListOf<Word>()
```

You are just adding elements to a standard collection structure, not something that compose can observe state changes for it to update your `LazyColumn`.

So please change it to this using `SnapshotStateList` and wrap it to a `remember{…}` so the list won't re-initialize on succeeding re-compositions

```
val wordData = remember { mutableStateListOf<Word>() }
```

Comment: Nice catch, z.y ;)